# UINavigationController : navigation confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am having confusion about push navigation controller and pop navigation controller. for example :

I have 5 view controller A , B ,C ,D ,E . I reach to E controller by push navigation from A. Now, after some task I need to navigate directly to the C controller. I know I can do this by using below method .

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController: animated:];
```

But I want to know that what about D controller ? will it be in stack or remove from stack ? 
If D would be in stack then how to remove it from the stack ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the method

```
popToViewController:C animated:YES
```

All the views till C are popped.

its like calling popViewControllerAnimated: 2 times (When you are at E).

If you want to follow the progress you can put some NSLog's in the viewDidUnload/Dealloc(no ARC).

Answer (score 1):

If you did not push controller D onto the stack, it's not on the stack.

If you did push controller D onto the stack, and you pop to a controller before it, it will be popped also, and thus not be on the stack anymore. If that wouldn't be the case, using an **UINavigationController** would be kind of pointless.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES]
```

viewControllers is an array that holds the views that are in the navigation controller sow if you want to reach the C view whitc is nr 2 in the stack just use the above command , 
Using this command the rest of the views  below C will be removed from the stack